# Correct way to do animations between views of the same type?

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I'm doing a training application that practices a set of multiple-choice questions. I'd like to do a slide animation between two questions - when the user correctly answers one question, it slides away to the left while the new one slides in from right.

Currently, my question/answer layout looks like this (question.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/question" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="8pt"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="5px"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    />
                <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/answers"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="5px"
                        >
                        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/answer_a"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="7pt"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/answer_b"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="7pt"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
                        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/answer_c"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="7pt"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After answering the question and evaluating the answer, I just changed the text of the question and the three answers. Pretty straightforward.

Now, I've tried using ViewFlipper to do the animations:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <include android:id="@+id/current_view" layout="@layout/question" />
    <include android:id="@+id/next_view"    layout="@layout/question" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

But that way I can't access the views in the current and next question separately via `findViewById`.

Do I need to have two same question layouts just with different IDs to do this? it seems redundant to me. Or is there another way to access *only* the question&answers in the second view?
Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the end I did this - I inflate the `questions.xml` layout every time I prepare a new question, add it to the flipper and flip it.
And as I don't want the flipper to become huge, I delete the previous old flips if there's more than one (basically always except the first time).

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);

    txtPracticeQuestion = (TextView)    layout.findViewById(R.id.question);
    rgrpPracticeAnswers = (RadioGroup)  layout.findViewById(R.id.answers);
    rbtnPracticeAnswerA = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.answer_a);
    rbtnPracticeAnswerB = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.answer_b);
    rbtnPracticeAnswerC = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.answer_c);

    rbtnPracticeAnswerA.setOnClickListener(this);
    rbtnPracticeAnswerB.setOnClickListener(this);
    rbtnPracticeAnswerC.setOnClickListener(this);

    txtPracticeQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.get("question").toString());
    rbtnPracticeAnswerA.setText(currentQuestion.get("answer_a").toString());
    rbtnPracticeAnswerB.setText(currentQuestion.get("answer_b").toString());
    rbtnPracticeAnswerC.setText(currentQuestion.get("answer_c").toString());

    if (flipper.getChildCount() > 1)
        flipper.removeViewAt(0);

    flipper.addView(layout);
```

Would this be the correct approach?